# How to find divisor to maximise remainder?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given two numbers `n` and `k`, find `x`, `1 <= x <= k` that maximises the remainder `n % x`.

For example, n = 20 and k = 10 the solution is x = 7 because the remainder 20 % 7 = 6 is maximum.

---

My solution to this is :

```
int n, k;
cin >> n >> k;
int max = 0;
for(int i = 1; i <= k; ++i)
{
  int xx = n - (n / i) * i; // or int xx = n % i;
  if(max < xx)
    max = xx;
}
cout << max << endl;
```

But my solution is `O(k)`. Is there any more efficient solution to this?

Comment: There might be a way to short-circuit the search by starting at high values of "k".   I don't think that would affect big-o.

Comment: This question is much more suitable for http://math.stackexchange.com/ IMO. The main problem at hand is algorithmic rather than programmatic.

Comment: @barakmanos . . . That is hard to say.  The OP knows how to solve the problem, but is looking for an efficient implementation.

Comment: Your code doesn't match the description.  It should be `int xx = n - (n / i) * i;`.  Or simply `int xx = n % i;`.  Or is the description wrong?  Also you should save the value of `i` when setting `max` as that is the value of `x` in the description.

Comment: @IronMensan thanks for that, my mistake

Comment: A small observation is that it is `O(min(n, k))`, because for i > n, the result is trivial, assuming the calculation of the mod is constant time (it is really not constant, but we seem to be assuming integer arithmetic on a computer).

Comment: @mnciitbhu A minor nit.  I'd reverse the sense of the if to match the positive logic of the problem:  if (xx > max).  Also, this is slightly faster because if you have more than one "i" where "xx" is identical, it will only write/modify "max" once.  Likewise, if trying to find the minimum, I'd do if (xx < min)

Comment: @CraigEstey: There is absolutely no reason why changin `max < xx` to `xx > max` would make _any_ difference in terms of speed. Neither of these statements return true if the values are identical. It might be better style but I guess that's very much debatable.

Comment: @barakmanos Probably better for SO than SE/math.  OP's description of the problem involved using "n % x" but when he coded it, instead of using "n % x", he used "n - (x / i) * i" instead of "n - (n / i) * i" aka "n % x".  That is, it was a bug in the code, not the wrong algorithm.  Besides, I just took a look at SE/math and the stuff there is orders of magnitude more sophisticated than this.  And I didn't see any C code posted there :-)

Comment: @matz No, it _does_ make a difference in speed.  "max < xx" means "xx >= max".  Consider: for xx in 1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,... When xx hits the 5, it will overwrite max on every subsequent loop, not just the first one.  With "xx < max", max is only overwritten on the first 5.  Thus, "xx < max" _is_ faster than "max > xx"

Comment: @matz Oops, my bad--you were correct.  My apologies.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: But this efficiency has nothing to do with programming methods.

Comment: @CraigEstey: I did not suggest to post it in MSE as it is posted here. The idea is to post it as a purely mathematical question.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Could you give an example?

Comment: @ColonelPanic read https://www.codechef.com/problems/GDOG

Comment: Think about the problem on paper before you code. **Hint:** Let n=60. Draw a graph of remainders 60 % x for 1 < x < 60. Where are the local maxima? Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not asymptotically faster, but faster, simply by going backwards and stopping when you know that you cannot do better.

Assume `k` is less than `n` (otherwise just output `k`).

```
int max = 0;
for(int i = k; i > 0 ; --i)
{
  int xx = n - (n / i) * i; // or int xx = n % i;
  if(max < xx)
    max = xx;
  if (i < max)
    break;   // all remaining values will be smaller than max, so break out!
}
cout << max << endl;
```

(This can be further improved by doing the for loop as long as `i > max`, thus eliminating one conditional statement, but I wrote it this way to make it more obvious)

Also, check Garey and Johnson's Computers and Intractability book to make sure this is not NP-Complete (I am sure I remember some problem in that book that looks a lot like this).  I'd do that before investing too much effort on trying to come up with better solutions.

Comment: First case of my solution. I should still take a look at the other cases though.

Answer (score 7):

This problem is equivalent to finding maximum of function `f(x)=n%x` in given range. Let's see how this function looks like:

[image: f(x)=n%x]

It is obvious that we could get the maximum sooner if we start with `x=k` and then decrease `x` while it makes any sense (until `x=max+1`). Also this diagram shows that for `x` larger than `sqrt(n)` we don't need to decrease `x` sequentially. Instead we could jump immediately to preceding local maximum.

```
int maxmod(const int n, int k)
{
    int max = 0;

    while (k > max + 1 && k > 4.0 * std::sqrt(n))
    {
        max = std::max(max, n % k);
        k = std::min(k - 1, 1 + n / (1 + n / k));
    }

    for (; k > max + 1; --k)
        max = std::max(max, n % k);

    return max;
}
```

Magic constant `4.0` allows to improve performance by decreasing number of iterations of the first (expensive) loop.

Worst case time complexity could be estimated as O(min(k, sqrt(n))). But for large enough `k` this estimation is probably too pessimistic: we could find maximum much sooner, and if `k` is significantly greater than `sqrt(n)` we need only 1 or 2 iterations to find it.

I did some tests to determine how many iterations are needed in the worst case for different values of `n`:

```
    n        max.iterations (both/loop1/loop2)
10^1..10^2    11   2   11
10^2..10^3    20   3   20
10^3..10^4    42   5   42
10^4..10^5    94  11   94
10^5..10^6   196  23  196
up to 10^7   379  43  379
up to 10^8   722  83  722
up to 10^9  1269 157 1269
```

Growth rate is noticeably better than O(sqrt(n)).

Answer (score 2):

For k > n the problem is trivial (take x = n+1).

For k < n, think about the graph of remainders n % x. It looks the same for all n: the remainders fall to zero at the harmonics of n: n/2, n/3, n/4, after which they jump up, then smoothly decrease  towards the next harmonic.

The solution is the rightmost local maximum below k. As a formula x =  `n//((n//k)+1)+1`  (where `//` is integer division).

[image]

Comment: What about n=60, k=12? Rightmost local maximum below k is 5, but global maximum is 6...

Comment: You're right, my graph shows that clearly! What's going on? The gradient is steeper with each harmonic (right to left). Thus I think you'll need to test the *two* harmonics left of k.

Comment: I don't think *two* is enough either.

Answer (score 1):

Nice little puzzle!

**Starting with the two trivial cases.**

for `n < k`: any `x` s.t. `n < x <= k` solves.

for `n = k`: `x = floor(k / 2) + 1` solves.

**My attempts.**

for `n > k`:

```
x = n
while (x > k) {
    x = ceil(n / 2)
}
```

^---- Did not work.

1. `x = floor(float(n) / (floor(float(n) / k) + 1)) + 1`
2. `x = ceil(float(n) / (floor(float(n) / k) + 1)) - 1`

^---- "*Close*" (whatever that means), but did not work.

My *pride* inclines me to mention that I was first to utilize the greatest `k`-bounded harmonic, given by `1.`

**Solution.**

Inline with other answers I simply check harmonics (term courtesy of @ColonelPanic) of `n` less than `k`, limiting by the present maximum value (courtesy of @TheGreatContini). This is the best of both worlds and I've tested with random integers between 0 and 10000000 with success.

```
int maximalModulus(int n, int k) {
    if (n < k) {
        return n;
    }
    else if (n == k) {
        return n % (k / 2 + 1);
    }
    else {
        int max = -1;
        int i = (n / k) + 1;
        int x = 1;
        while (x > max + 1) {
            x = (n / i) + 1;
            if (n%x > max) {
                max = n%x;
            }
            ++i;
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

**Performance tests:**
http://cpp.sh/72q6

Sample output:

```
Average number of loops:
bruteForce: 516
theGreatContini: 242.8
evgenyKluev: 2.28
maximalModulus: 1.36 // My solution
```

Answer (score 1):

*waves hands around*

No value of `x` which is a factor of `n` can produce the maximum `n%x`, since if `x` is a factor of `n` then `n%x=0`.

Therefore, you would like a procedure which avoids considering any `x` that is a factor of `n`. But this means you want an easy way to know if `x` is a factor. If that were possible you would be able to do an easy prime factorization.

Since there [is not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Difficulty_and_complexity) a known easy way to do prime factorization there cannot be an "easy" way to solve your problem (I don't think you're going to find a single formula, some kind of search will be necessary).

That said, the prime factorization literature has cunning ways of getting factors quickly relative to a naive search, so perhaps it can be leveraged to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wrong for sure, but it looks to me that it depends on if `n < k` or not.

I mean, if `n < k`, `n%(n+1)` gives you the maximum, so `x = (n+1)`.

Well, on the other hand, you can start from `j = k` and go back evaluating `n%j` until it's equal to `n`, thus `x = j` is what you are looking for and you'll get it in max `k` steps... Too much, is it?

Answer (score -1):

Okay, we want to know divisor that gives maximum remainder;

let `n` be a number to be divided and `i` be the divisor.

we are interested to find the maximum remainder when `n` is divided by `i`, for all `i<n`.

we know that, `remainder = n - (n/i) * i //equivalent to n%i`

If we observe the above equation to get maximum `remainder` we have to **minimize** `(n/i)*i`

minimum of `n/i` for any `i<n` is `1`.

Note that, `n/i == 1`, for `i<n`, if and only if `i>n/2`

now we have, `i>n/2`.

The least possible value greater than `n/2` is `n/2+1`.

**Therefore, the divisor that gives maximum remainder, `i = n/2+1`**

Here is the code in C++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int maxRemainderDivisor(int n){
    n = n>>1;
    return n+1;
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<maxRemainderDivisor(n)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Time complexity: O(1)**